# Delete/remove Solr configuration from ZooKeeper using zkcli?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

We have some old Solr configs in ZK and that we need to cleanup/delete.

The configs are at /configs/AAA, /configs/BBB, etc.  (There are other configs under /configs as well.)

The Solr zkcli.sh script and docs provide no direction for deleting a config.  The only thing that looks obvious is the "clear" parameter, but the docs and zkcli only give the example `-cmd clear /solr`.  I thought `./zkcli -cmd clear /configs/AAA` might work, but without being able to find much information on the internet, I'm leery of inadvertently deleting the wrong thing.

If I want to delete the old configs, do I use clear, and if so, is the path parameter /configs/?

Thanks

Comment: No, and the Solr cloud folks said it is not supported yet.

Comment: Is there a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You missed the -z parameter which is mandatory (Zookeeper-3.4.8).

The correct command for deleting configset AAA on Solr (v.6.1.0) running on localhost with zookeeper on port 2181 is:

```
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd clear -z "localhost:2181" /configs/AAA
```

when in the root directory of Solr.

So to answer your question: Yes, you can use clear, and the path should be /configs/< name of configset >

Resources:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities

Comment: By the way, it's also possible to clear a single file within a config set. e.g `zkcli.sh -cmd clear -z localhost:2181 /configs/dummy/managed-schema.og`

Answer (score 6):

From within your zookeeper bin directory, start `zkCli.sh`, this will open zookeeper console.

Then fire the following command to delete a node/config:

```
rmr /configs
```

Comment: In recent ZooKeeper versions, it seems to be `deleteall` instead of `rmr` now.