# SolrCore Initialization Failures - mail, solr, atom, tika, db

Tags: java, search, solr, solr8

[SolrCore Initialization Failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R0xy.png)
I have a 3 node solr 8.11.1 setup (port 8983) with 3 node external zookeeper 3.7.1 (p 2181). After I did a clean setup, I see Solr Core Initialization error in the admin console. The error is below. I have no idea how to avoid this error? Any help will be appreciated.
[solr error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ysZ.png)

```
   solr: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
   atom: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
   tika: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
   db: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
```

Thanks
Joby

Here is the error from the log.

2022-07-13 02:57:58.734 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-21-thread-2-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [c:db   x:db] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
2022-07-13 02:57:58.740 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-21-thread-2-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [c:solr   x:solr] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
2022-07-13 02:57:58.741 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-21-thread-2-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [c:tika   x:tika] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
2022-07-13 02:57:58.743 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-21-thread-3-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [c:mail   x:mail] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
2022-07-13 02:57:58.745 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [c:atom   x:atom] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
2022-07-13 02:57:58.747 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-4-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [atom]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [atom]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:902) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [atom]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1473) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1876) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
2022-07-13 02:57:58.747 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-4-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [db]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [db]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:902) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [db]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1473) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1876) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
2022-07-13 02:57:58.747 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-4-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mail]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mail]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:902) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mail]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1473) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1876) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
2022-07-13 02:57:58.747 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-4-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [solr]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [solr]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:902) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [solr]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1473) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1876) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
2022-07-13 02:57:58.747 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-4-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.1.1:3001_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [tika]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [tika]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:902) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_331]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [tika]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1473) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1876) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:2194) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1906) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1843) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1443) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$11(CoreContainer.java:873) ~[?:?]
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
... 5 more

Comment: The log will have the actual stack trace that tells you what the underlying issue is. Start by looking at that (either under Logging in the web interface, by looking in the log directory under Solr, or start Solr in the foreground with `-f` and get the logs directly. If you're running Solr in Docker or k8s, the log will be available as the default output.

Comment: I updated the question with the error from the Log.

Answer (score 0):

Your zookeeper has configuration details for a set of collections, but your Solr installation does not have those collections (since you did a clean install).

If you never removed the configuration data from zookeeper, there is already an expected state of the cluster present in zookeeper - which is no longer a correct representation of how the actual cluster is.

You can refer to [Delete/remove Solr configuration from ZooKeeper using zkcli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589942/delete-remove-solr-configuration-from-zookeeper-using-zkcli) for how to remove the stored configuration.

> `./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd clear -z "localhost:2181" /configs/AAA`

Comment: Still I am getting the same error. 
command: zkcli.sh -cmd clear -z "192.168.1.1:2181, 192.168.1.2:2181,192.168.1.3:2181" /configs/solr
INFO  - 2022-07-14 13:49:53.761; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
INFO  - 2022-07-14 13:49:53.793; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has connected
INFO  - 2022-07-14 13:49:53.793; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Client is connected to ZooKeeper command: zkcli.sh -cmd clear -z "192.168.1.1:2181, 192.168.1.2:2181,192.168.1.3:2181" /configs/solr

Comment: I restarted the zookeeper and Solr even after I run the zkcli commands to remove the configs, Still I am getting the same error. I am using Zookeeper 3.7.1 and Solr 8.11.1

Comment: anybody can help?